# How to know that some external app has finished uploading image?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-sdcard

My app shares a temporary image with other apps when a user clicks on the Share button (it calls Android share dialog). The image is saved into publicly accessible folder /sdcard/download/ on SD card.

I would like to know when some external app (Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, etc.) has finished uploading or working with the image so that I can safely delete it.

Which listener should I implement in my app?

Comment: Are they really not throw any message?

Comment: did you get the answer?